# Run an Oracle query in PHP and automatically assign columns as variables

Tags: php, sql, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I would like to create a PHP file that will run an Oracle select statement that has 20 columns and automatically generate variables and assign values based on the column names.

The pseudocode looks like this:

```
$sql = "select col1,col2,col3,col4, etc. from table";

$stid = oci_parse($abcConn, $sql);
oci_execute($stid);
```

I would like the results of this to be 20 new variables set to their appropriate value, i.e. `$col1`, `$col2`, `$col3`, etc.

This query will always bring back one row making it simple.

Comment: You didn't explain what specific issue you encountered while doing this.

Comment: I didn't get an error but I am missing the key components of getting the results and assigning the results to individual variables. I have added to the question to explain more.

Comment: WHat do you mean, "automatically generate variables??"  You just call oci_fetch_array and index the results.  There are a million examples on the web.

Comment: @OldProgrammer can you link to an example? I couldn't find one that does what I explained I am trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function is what you are looking for:

```
$sql = 'select col1,col2,col3,col4, etc. from table';

$stid = oci_parse($abcConn, $sql);
oci_execute($stid);

extract(oci_fetch_assoc($stid));

// $COL1, $COL2, etc. are now set.
```

Note that by default Oracle returns field names in upper case. Since variable names in PHP are case-sensitive, alias the field names in your query if you want your variables to be lower or mixed case.

Comment: Thank you @TimClutton that is exactly what I was looking for! Much appreciated!